# How to completely unistall Samba and the corresponding files on /etc directory

Tags: samba

I have used the below commands to uninstall samba:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge samba
sudo apt-get remove --purge smbclient libsmbclient
```

But when i search for samba corresponding files on my Nautilus Browser it still shows me some samba files as showed in the picture below.

[image: Samba Related Files]

Comment: Maybe "sudo apt-get autoremove samba samba-common && sudo apt-get purge samba samba-common" will help? Last step should remove any configuration file you may have

Comment: Naah after using the code above the files still exist

Comment: Why are you trying to remove Samba?

Comment: Cause i want to reinstall it but first i want to uninstall it fully so i dont have some problems with the new configurations i want to make